# Unable to Create an Issue for an Organization Repo Using GitHub API v3

Tags: curl, github, github-api, github-api-v3

I want to create an issue for an org repo using enterprise GitHub API, but unable to do that with `curl`

I am using

```
curl -u $username -d '{"title":"Big Files List", "label":"big files","body": "'$(find  -type f -size +150M)'"}'    https://$hostname/api/v3/repos/orgs/$orgName/$repoName/issues -k
```

The message in the response I got back was `"Not Found"`

I've checked `https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue`, which only talks about user's repo instead of organization repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering an organization repository is a Git repo following the same URL structure as any other repos, you can still follow [GitHub API V3 issue "create an issue"](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue)

```
curl -k -u $username \
     -d '{"title":"Big Files List", "label":"big files","body": "'$(find  -type f -size +150M)'"}' \
     https://$hostname/api/v3/repos/$orgName/$repoName/issues
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: But now it gives me another error which is not directly related to the original issue. It says "body" is not an object. Probably the expression of `$(find  -type f -size +150M)` is not expanded correctly within the command. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check if using double quotes instead of simple helps. It depends on the shell used.

Comment: it works fine when I replace `'$(find  -type f -size +150M)'` with a string, so I must work around this part to solve the issue. The double/single quotes anywhere else work.